# CustomLineCap FillPath instead of StrokePath?

Tags: c#, drawing2d

I am trying to write a plugin for Paint.Net but for support I am currently writing the code in Visual Studio 2010 using C#. What I am trying to acheive is to make a curve and make a custom line cap for it. I have acheived the major functionality by writing the following code;

```
SolidBrush myBrushColor1 = new SolidBrush(Amount4);
Pen myPen = new Pen(myBrushColor1, Amount7);
System.Drawing.Point[] pts = { new System.Drawing.Point(0,0), new System.Drawing.Point(0,3), new System.Drawing.Point(3, 0)};
System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath path = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
path.AddPolygon(pts);
System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CustomLineCap lineCap = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CustomLineCap(null, path);

Rectangle arcRect = new Rectangle(0,0,100,100);
g.DrawArc(myPen, arcRect , -90, 90);
```

This is exactly what I want to acheive but I want to fill the Polygon created as a CustomEndCap. Right now it is drawn as outline. I have googled it and found that I have to change `CustomLineCap(null, path);`  to `CustomLineCap(path, null);`

I changed the code and provided path as fillpath and null as strokepath but it started giving Exception "An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Not implemented".

What I need to do here?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# Drawing2D" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Sorry, but this is my very first post here. Will keep that in mind for future.

Comment: [Cross-posted on social.msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/588903ca-17c6-4ea6-99fb-e0cd3c5ea6df/c-drawing2d-customlinecap-fillpath-insetad-of-strokepath?forum=csharplanguage).

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use the right [`CustomLineCap` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.customlinecap.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0):

```
var lineCap = new CustomLineCap(fillPath, null);
```

The first constructor parameter is `fillPath` and the second one is `strokePath`. To draw a filled line cap, we need to create a `GraphicsPath` object (`fillPath`), add a filled rectangle to it and create a `Pen` with a custom end cap.
The following method draws an end cap to an arc (Note that there are redundant code in the question and this is a cleaned and working example):

```
private void DrawArcWithFilledEndCap(Graphics g)
{
    // fillPath specifies the size of the end cap.
    GraphicsPath fillPath = new GraphicsPath();
    // fillPath should intercept the negative y-axis. (MSDN spec)
    fillPath.AddRectangle(new RectangleF(-2, -2, 4, 4));
    CustomLineCap lineCap = new CustomLineCap(fillPath, null);
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 1.0f) { CustomEndCap = lineCap };

    Rectangle arcRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
    g.DrawArc(pen, arcRect, -90, 90);
}
```

The result is:

[image]

Please refer to [CustomLineCap constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.customlinecap.-ctor) for details.

For future reference, the following method draws both empty and filled caps to a line:

```
private void DrawLineCaps(Graphics g)
{
    GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
    path.AddLine(new Point(30, 30), new Point(260, 30));

    GraphicsPath strokePath = new GraphicsPath();
    strokePath.AddRectangle(new RectangleF(-2, 0, 4, 4));

    GraphicsPath fillPath = new GraphicsPath();
    fillPath.AddRectangle(new RectangleF(-2, -2, 4, 4));

    var startLineCap = new CustomLineCap(null, strokePath);
    var endLineCap = new CustomLineCap(fillPath, null);

    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
    pen.CustomStartCap = startLineCap;
    pen.CustomEndCap = endLineCap;

    g.DrawPath(pen, path);
}
```

The result is

[image]